# Get selected menu item & display the corresponding item on frame

Tags: java, swing, menu, jframe, menuitem

I have 3 conditions (3 menu items in menu).  In those 3 items, how to get one menu item selected as soon as the frame opens and displays the content of that item by default?

Later on if we select other menu items, then corresponding contents on the frame will be displayed as usual. I have written very lengthy code for this GUI, so unable to paste here. But got stuck up at this point.

Comment: for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) , and for future readers..., post runnable code that contains JFrame with 3 JMenuItems,

Comment: Use a `CardLayout` to change between the different views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply invoke the `actionPerformed()` method of your `ActionListener` after your GUI is fully constructed. This is particularly easy if you have implemented the `Action` interface, as shown in [*How to Use Actions*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html).

Using this [example](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/graphpanel), add the following line near `setVisible()` to simulate adding a few random nodes to the graph:

```
gp.control.random.actionPerformed(new ActionEvent(gp, 0, null));
```

To simulate clicking a button, this line simulates adding a selected node:

```
gp.control.defaultButton.doClick();
```

Answer (score 1):

By default all menu items are not selected when they are created. To make a menu item selected before you show it in your application you should change the state of the model. For the `JMenu` items it's easy by `setSelected(true)` and `setPopupMenuVisible(true)`. For the `JMenuItem` items you have to `setArmed(true)`. You can return back to the default state in the `actionPerformed`.